# Chrome: Every browser window has a small rectangle with the word "Google" in the upper right quadrant?

Tags: google-chrome

This little box does not seem to do anything and I would like to know what it is for and/or how to get rid of it. I have Chrome on a different machine and it does not exhibit this behavior. Reloading the page has no effect, clicking on the box does not have an effect.

EDIT: I added the screenshot. My version of Chrome is less than a year old. Would rather turn this off than re-installing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0dJO.png)

Comment: upload a pic it will help people understand your problem

Comment: Older versions of Chrome did this IIRC.  If you have one of these oldwr vwrsions it's very out of date.  Try updating or reinstalling from chrome.google.com.

Comment: @LawrenceC This version is new enough to be using the Material Design UI -- it can't be that old.